# How to show * patterns in specific div using javascript looping

Tags: javascript, html

The current code show * pattern in document but i want it to show in the specific div. i have a div with #result. I want to show the the pattern in `#result` div.

```
<script>
  var maxs = 1;

  for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
    for(var x=1;x<=maxs;x++){
      document.write("*");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
   maxs++
  }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property to set the `HTML` and select the element using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

`+=` will merge new HTML with existing HTML and will replace the `inner-html` of the element with merged `html`

```js
var maxs = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (var x = 1; x <= maxs; x++) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "*";
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<br>";
  maxs++
}
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

*Or cache the `html` and `.innerHTML` only once after the loop which will update the `DOM` only once*

```js
var maxs = 1;
var html = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (var x = 1; x <= maxs; x++) {
    html += "*";
  }
  html += "<br>";
  maxs++
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get div element with id `result` using **[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)** and then use **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property of dom element to update html content.

```js
var maxs = 1,
  div = document.getElementById('result');

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (var x = 1; x <= maxs; x++) {
    div.innerHTML += "*";
  }
  div.innerHTML += "<br>";
  maxs++
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById("result").textContent = "*"
```

You can also use `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, add a `div` placeholder to update the result. Also updating `DOM` for every `for loop` iteration is expensive, so better `cache` it by using a temporary variable `output` and then in the end set the `innerHTML` property of the `div` to this `output`.

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
var maxs = 1;
var output="";  
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
    for(var x=1;x<=maxs;x++){
        output +="*";
    }
    output +="<br/>";
    maxs++;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
</script>
```